# Adaptive Subdivision Hides Parts of Mesh

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm using Adaptive Subdivison Surface on a model and some sections of the mesh just dissapear when I go in render mode. I'm using the material Displacement mode to "Both". Also, I'm using Simple Subdivision Surface Modifier.

Not sure what is happening. Googling didn't return any useful results, either. 
Is the topology somehow affecting the hiding?

Solid Mode:
[image]

Rendered mode: 
[image: Rendered -- Parts Of Mesh Culled]

Comment: check your normals, is does look like half of your mesh is inside out, but that still doesn't explain your issue.

Comment: Yeah. That was my initial assumption. I had aligned all normals externally and I even visually confirmed all were pointing outwards. However, I still faced the same issue when moving over to the rendered view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to the ngons the mesh has. Convert them to quads and try rendering again. Also, it seems that this only happens when the shading is flat.

Comment: The smooth shading worked. Converting to quads didn't do much. So, does it mean flat shading will not work with adaptive subsurf mods?

Comment: Adaptative subdivision and flat shading works for me, but I get holes or missing faces with ngons and flat shading.